# In SQL select and count all entries where with same value in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like in an mysql-database.

```
    id section number name
     1 A       1234   fred
     2 B       5678   mo
     3 B       1234   fred
     4 C       8901   lou
     5 A       8901   lou
     6 A       2345   lee
     7 B       2345   lee
     8 C       2345   lee
     9 A       6789   paul
    10 B       1234   fred
```

This is my table and i need to get all numbers is in more then one section with the name of the section. like this

```
    id section number name
     1 A       1234   fred
     3 B       1234   fred
```

Fred is in section A and B.
In my solution i get this

```
    id section number count name
     1 A       1234   1     fred
     3 B       1234   2     fred
     6 A       2345   1     lee
     7 B       2345   1     lee
     8 C       2345   1     lee
     2 B       5678   1     mo
     9 A       6789   1     paul
     4 C       8901   1     lou
     5 A       8901   1     lou
```

in my way i try is sql select

```
   SELECT id, section, number, count(number) AS count, name
   FROM table
   GROUP BY section, number
   ORDER BY number
```

Is is the right way? How can i improve that for mor number columns, if have 3 numbercolumns

```
   id section number1 number2 number3 name
```

Now i do this with 3 sql-statements

Comment: Why the MS SQL Server tag? How's that product involved?

Comment: You've got a typo here: GROUP BY setion

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." Follow that rule, and your life will be much easier. (I know MySQL does things their own way when it comes to GROUP BY, somewhat unpredictable if you don't follow this rule...)

Comment: @jarlh I lost all hope that people will differentiate them see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system

Comment: Thanks
if i try this my GROUP BY looks so
GROUP BY section, number, name, id
the are no group by my it looks like select * from
is it right, the the ordering from the GROUP BY is importent for the result.

Comment: And how can i combine the 3 number columns?